# how to set AD attributes values without using admin privilege in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dns, active-directory

i set a value into my custom AD attribute using ldap_mod_ext function.

but it gives return code 50.

i refer error codes 50 is a insufficient privilage.

how can i set the value in AD without any privilege?

note:i set the value is to,which one user in login.

Comment: That would make security superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

We cant set the value in AD attribute,without the domain admin privillage.